# Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our best practices for more details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, the question would be how to solve the warning "Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our best practices for more details."

Comment: the question how can i solve it ??